# How to handle infrastructure for authentication with RN app, Shopify and Firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, shopify, aws-amplify

For a client I've build a React Native app. App works great however the client wants to get rid of the current backend (not built by me) because of budget cuts. Currently the app only uses the backend for user authentication.

The client wants to build a Shopify webshop to handle promotions and to sell physical products. The customers should be able to login in the app with the same credentials as in the Shopify webshop. Furthermore it would be nice to have a Firebase or AWS Amplify BaaS to handle integrations with other services. Currently they use Revenuecat for in app purchases, segment.io for emails, UXcam for gathering user behaviour in the app and Firebase Analytics for general Analytics.

It would be nice to have a single place of all the user data and not have all the different data in different services. Furthermore we would like to have the option to send push notifications in the future.

It would be an option to not use a BaaS and use the Shopify API for user authentication. However this would make it hard to integrate with other services and limit future features.

So long story short, I want to use Firebase or AWS Amplify as a BaaS. But how would you handle authentication for the app and for the shopify webshop? Shopify has it's own authentication system.
Furthermore I would like some opinions to potential drawbacks of this approach

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Found a solution? Try to do the same...

Comment: @Jonas unfortunately no

Answer (score 0):

You can create simple authentication flow for a react native application and once authenticated then you can get the shopify key from the database  (firebase realtime database or firestore) which will be secured by the rules. [Firebase Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/)

Hope this helps

Comment: So a user would login in the webshop with shopify and on the app with shopify api as well? And then you would update data from the app directly into firebase?

Comment: So each user gets a unique ID from Shopify auth, and saves that ID in an open branch of  google firebase database (make the rules for only read and write by admin). After auth, if you find the ID in the branch. You have authenticated else error (or new user based on flow). Hope this helps